# Show possible completions in zsh (possible-completions in bash)

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have recently switched to zsh from bash. Deep in my inputrc, I had `"\e[/": possible-completions` set. This allowed me to see all completions at a given point, without applying them. This was really useful if I had typed `ls folder/` and wanted to see what is in the folder. However, I can't seem to find this feature in zsh.

I actually cannot even find any mention of the option in bash on google, either, but it is in the man pages.

Is there any way to use this feature in zsh?

Answer (score 1):

In zsh, a command that you can bind to a key is called a [widget](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Widgets). There are several [built-in widgets for completion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Completion), including [`list-choices`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-list_002dchoices), which I think is what you're looking for. It's bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> by default.

But zsh offers a lot more possibilities than bash, so you may want to explore a bit. There are a few basic [options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Completion-3) related to completion, and then there's a huge [completion system](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System) that is very powerful, but can be hard to configure from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with zsh and oh-my-zsh, if I understood it properly. If not, install oh-my-zsh.

**zsh-autosuggestions Installation**

**Manual (Git Clone)**

Clone this repository somewhere on your machine. This guide will assume ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions.

```
 git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions
```

Add the following to your .zshrc:

```
 source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh
```

Start a new terminal session.

**Oh My Zsh**

Clone this repository into $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins (by default ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins)

```
 git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-~/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions
```

Add the plugin to the list of plugins for Oh My Zsh to load (inside ~/.zshrc):

```
 plugins=(zsh-autosuggestions)
```

Start a new terminal session.

Source:
GitHub link to package:
https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
Link to install info:
https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/master/INSTALL.md